# Convert array of objects to an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, map, array

I have an array of objects with below value

```
var arr = 
[{"Id":"0QL8W000006RHl1WAG","Sortorder":"1"}, 
          {"Id":"0QL8W000006RHl0WAG","Sortorder":"2"}, 
           {"Id":"0QL8W000006RHl2WAG","Sortorder":"3"}
          ]
```

Now I want to convert it to an object with below format.

```
var arr = {0QL8W000006RHl1WAG=1,0QL8W000006RHl0WAG=2,0QL8W000006RHl2WAG=3}
```

I have really tried most of the javascript methods for this with no success.

Please help on this. It's really very very urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the desired output , you essentially need a JS [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) data structure.

Why are we using a Map over a JS object : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps

**Step 1** : Convert each object in the array to an array itself using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method :

```
const arrayObj = [{"Id":"0QL8W000006RHl1WAG","Sortorder":"1"}, {"Id":"0QL8W000006RHl0WAG","Sortorder":"2"}, {"Id":"0QL8W000006RHl2WAG","Sortorder":"3"} ];

const mappedArrayObj = arrayObj.map(obj => [obj.Id, obj.Sortorder]);
```

Our 1st step produced an array of array(`mappedArrayObj`) as below:

```
[
  [ '0QL8W000006RHl1WAG', '1' ],
  [ '0QL8W000006RHl0WAG', '2' ],
  [ '0QL8W000006RHl2WAG', '3' ]
]
```

**Step 2** : Convert the `mappedArrayObj` to a JS map using Map constructor as below :

```
const mapOfObjects = new Map(mappedArrayObj);
```

This will produce output (`console.log(mapOfObjects);`) as below :

```
{
  '0QL8W000006RHl1WAG' => '1',
  '0QL8W000006RHl0WAG' => '2',
  '0QL8W000006RHl2WAG' => '3'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but it's not working fine.

I've tried the above code but in console it;s showing 

[object Map]

I've tried it like this 

 const map = new Map(component.get("v.StoreSortOrder").map((obj) => [obj.Id, obj.Sortorder]));

  alert('map11----'+map);

Output - map11---- [object Map]

Please help

Comment: alert & console function will stringify the object and hence , you are observing [object Map]
try with : console.log("output ", map) -> Notice the comma in the function.

Comment: You can check this link : https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3z2e8w2ct

Comment: Thanks a ton.. It's working perfect.

Getting below output in the console
{'0QL8W000006RHl1WAG' => '1', '0QL8W000006RHl0WAG' => '4', '0QL8W000006RHl2WAG' => '5'}

I need to do one more thing now.

Need to remove the quotes mark around the key/value pair.
Hence the final output should be

{0QL8W000006RHl1WAG=>1, 0QL8W000006RHl0WAG=>4,0QL8W000006RHl2WAG=> 5}

Please guide on this as well.

Comment: Welcome , you can remove the quote from the number in the value but since map key "0QL8W000006RHl1WAG" is alpha-numeric , we cannot remove it.
You are trying to convert map to a string ?

Comment: No.. I need to create a map of Map<Id,Integer>.
That's why need to remove the quotes from everywhere

Comment: Ok . In this case , you do not need to remove quotes from map key. For converting the values to number - https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3z2e8w2ct

Comment: I got this.
In Salesforce, I can use Id.valueOf(String)  to convert this into Id.

Thanks a ton Rohit for your help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144543/discussion-between-rohit-and-parvindra-singh).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to @Rohit's approach is to use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) functionality:

```js
const arrayObj = [{"Id":"0QL8W000006RHl1WAG","Sortorder":"1"}, {"Id":"0QL8W000006RHl0WAG","Sortorder":"2"}, {"Id":"0QL8W000006RHl2WAG","Sortorder":"3"} ];

const result = arrayObj.reduce(
    (target, item) => (target[item.Id] = item.Sortorder, target),
    {});
```

The `{}` is the initial empty object to return (what becomes the `target` in the reducer), while the "reducer function" simply:

1. Sets the property on that object with the name taken from the item's `Id` and sets it to the item's `Sortorder` (`target[item.Id] = item.Sortorder`) then
2. Uses the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to ensure that the function returns the `target` object for the reducer chaining (`, target`).

By "chaining" the `target` object in this way, this avoids creating garbage that must be collected - we simply add properties to that one JavaScript object.

Comment: Nice approach @phil 